# how to save an activity state?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have received the value through using the onAcitivityResult.
However, when moving to another Acitivity, this value is initialized. I want to save the received value using save instance state.

```
private static final int TEMP_REQUEST_CODE=5;
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(requestCode==TEMP_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
        String HTempTxt=data.getStringExtra("valuehtemp");
        String LTempTxt=data.getStringExtra("valueltemp");
        LTempText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ltemp);
        HTempText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.htemp);
        HTempText.setText(HTempTxt);
        LTempText.setText(LTempTxt);
    }
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_infostate);

TempButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_temp);
LTempText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ltemp);
HTempText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.htemp);

TempButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettempActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,TEMP_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean "the value is initialized"? How do you "move to another `Activity`? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly but usually you override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and write the state values you want to change to Bundle

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
savedInstanceState.putString("String", "Hi Android");
}
```

it will get passed to onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState() where you can receive the values from activity:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("Boolean");
double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("Double");
int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("Int");
String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("String");
}
```

or fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
    double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
    int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
    String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In most modern applications, you'll follow a design pattern like MVP or MVVM, where the "Model" is responsible for persistent storage. That storage can be something that exists in the Application's memory, is written to a database, or is uploaded to a server.

In your case, you could probably just persist it in Application memory by storing it in a static field, and read from it when your Activity is initialised:

```
class TempData {
  final String hTemp, lTemp;
 
  TempData(String hTemp, String lTemp) {
    this.hTemp = hTemp;
    this.lTemp = lTemp;
  }

  //Copy constructor
  TempData(TempData data) {
    this(data.hTemp, data.lTemp);
  }
}
```

```
//Singleton
class TempDataRepo {

  private static TempDataRepo instance = null;
 
  static TempDataRepo instance() {
    if(instance == null)
      instance = new TempDataRepo();
    return instance;
  }

  private TempData cached;

  private TempDataRepo() {
    cached = null;
  }

  void write(TempData in) {
    cached = in;
  }

  @Nullable
  TempData read() { 
    return cached == null ? null : new TempData(cached);
  }
}
```

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

  //onCreate...
  final TempData data = TempDataRepo.instance().read();
  if(data != null) {
    //apply it..
    ...setText(data.hTemp);
    ...setText(data.lTemp);
  }

  //onActivityResult...
  final String hTempTxt=data.getStringExtra("valuehtemp");
  final String lTempTxt=data.getStringExtra("valueltemp");
  final TempData data = new TempData(hTempText, lTempTxt);
  TempDataRepo.instance().write(new TempData(hTempText, lTempTxt);
}
```